# Query CosmosDB with CosmosClient and map to object

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, cosmosclient

Right now I have the following code to query my CosmosDB:

```
var streamIterator = containerLogs.GetItemQueryStreamIterator("SELECT * FROM mycontainer");

while (streamIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var results = await streamIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    var stream = results.Content;
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    // typeof what..?
    //var dbDocuments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<???>(data);
}
```

The variable `data` will contain the following JSON:

```
{
    "_rid": "wDhMAJ9xYHE=",
    "Documents": [{
        "id": "c05c4eee-32d4-458a-8ae8-d22dd0f93839",
        "CustomProperty1": "Value 1",
        "CustomProperty2": "Value 2",
        "_rid": "wDhMAJ9xYHECAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs\/wDhMAA==\/colls\/wDhMAJ9xYHE=\/docs\/wDhMAJ9xYHECAAAAAAAAAA==\/",
        "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-7167-28c107aa01d6\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments\/",
        "_ts": 1597319093
    }],
    "_count": 1
}
```

The `Documents` part is my actual "domain" model. How can I easily map this back to a list of my domain model class? I used the same class to write to CosmosDB.

The model looks like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string CustomProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string CustomProperty1 {get;set;}
}
```

So how can I query my CosmosDB so that it returns a list of this class?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Where does streamIterator come from?

Comment: I have added the line where `streamIterator` comes from. I'm using the package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` version 3.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L99) that I found helpful. The simpler case is to used the typed `GetItemQueryIterator<MyModel>`, but there is also a [stream deserialization](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L122) example.